# How to change the if statement to for statement without affecting the outcome in google apps script?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k144G.png)

Hello,

I want to copy the orders from five customers to Order History table whenever the orders had been submitted or updated. This is my code:

```
function onEdit(e){

  const dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Singapore', 'HH:mm:ss');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet ();
  var direction = SpreadsheetApp.Direction
  var aLast = ss.getRange("I"+(ss.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(direction.UP).getRow()
  var destRange = ss.getRange(aLast+1,9);

  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart >= 4) {
    if (e.value == 'Update' || e.value == 'Submit') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(dt);
      
      if(e.range.rowStart = 4) {
        var order1 = ss.getRange ("A4:G4");
        order1.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      } else if (e.range.rowStart = 5){
        var order2 = ss.getRange ("A5:G5");
        order2.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      } else if (e.range.rowStart = 6){
        var order3 = ss.getRange ("A6:G6");
        order3.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      } else if (e.range.rowStart = 7){
        var order4 = ss.getRange ("A7:G7");
        order4.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      } else if (e.range.rowStart = 8){
        var order5 = ss.getRange ("A8:G8");
        order5.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      }
      
      source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    }
  } 
}
```

However, when I submitted or updated the order from `Customer 2`, the order been copied into Order History table will still be the order from `Customer 1`. I think the reason is because of this line of code: `if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart >= 4)` where the `>=4` is the main problem. However, I'm not sure how to change `if statement` to `for loop` because this line of code is used to assist in printing the current timestamp in `column G` whenever `column F` shows `Update` or `Submit`.

Hope to get some guidance from expert, really appreaciate for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I thought that each if statement is required to be modified.

  - For example, in the case of `if(e.range.rowStart = 4) {`, `4` is assigned to `e.range.rowStart`. In your script, the numbers from 4 to 8 are put. In these cases, the if statement is always `true`. By this, the script of 1st if statement is always run. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- And, about `source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});`, in your script, `souece` is not declared. So I think that an error occurs at this line.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Singapore', 'HH:mm:ss');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet ();
  var direction = SpreadsheetApp.Direction
  var aLast = ss.getRange("I"+(ss.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(direction.UP).getRow()
  var destRange = ss.getRange(aLast+1,9);

  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart >= 4) {
    if (e.value == 'Update' || e.value == 'Submit') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(dt);
      
      if(e.range.rowStart == 4) {  // Modified
        var order1 = ss.getRange ("A4:G4");
        order1.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      } else if (e.range.rowStart == 5){  // Modified
        var order2 = ss.getRange ("A5:G5");
        order2.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      } else if (e.range.rowStart == 6){  // Modified
        var order3 = ss.getRange ("A6:G6");
        order3.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      } else if (e.range.rowStart == 7){  // Modified
        var order4 = ss.getRange ("A7:G7");
        order4.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      } else if (e.range.rowStart == 8){  // Modified
        var order5 = ss.getRange ("A8:G8");
        order5.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      }
      
      // source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});    // Modified. I thought that this line mignt be able to be removed.
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    }
  } 
}
```

#### Reference:

- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, really appreciate your solution! It works perfectly for me. May I know what is the purpose of adding this line: `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))` into the script?

Comment: @desmond Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))`, I had used for checking the values of the event object `e`. And, I forgot to remove this when I posted this answer. I apologize for this. Now I updated my answer.

Comment: Really appreciate your help! I was struggling to solve this problem for the past few days but I couldn't solve it by myself as I'm quite new to scripting. Thank you!